# Why do we need to hit the Stirling engine to start it?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

We are experimenting on [Stirling engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_engine). We are using an alpha-type Stirling engine. Once one starts heating the one chamber, the piston will not move immediately. You can wait for long, but it wouldn't start until you give it a push for the first time. What's the reason for this?

Comment: There are plenty of mechanical things out there that need a little (finely calibrated) "persuasion" to start going. Often it is a friction problem, so you need to lubricate or replace the bearings. Still, a nice rubber mallet can go a long ways to getting things going on a cold morning.

Comment: @JonCuster Yeah! Percussive maintenance. The old engineers' universal tool! :-) (Disclaimer: I'm an engineer :-)

Answer (score 20):

This is due to *stiction* (static friction) which is a very common problem in piston/cylinder devices that use air to move the piston. When at rest, the piston sticks in the cylinder because the coefficient of static friction is greater than that for dynamic (sliding) friction. When the pressure rises enough, there comes the *breakaway point* where the piston suddenly jumps into motion. If the pressure does not reach the breakaway point, the piston stays stuck until you hit it to break it loose.

Pneumomechanical actuators called *air cylinders* are used in mechanical engineering machinery to move cams and levers and to prevent the pistons in them from getting stuck it is necessary to install a *spring return* which preloads the piston with a force that helps it not get stuck.

The legend in the mechanical engineering world is that everyone's first complex mechanism is powered by air acting in air cylinders, and that none of the tools one designs after that is.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the description of the four stage process, quoted from Wikipedia:

> 1. Power piston has compressed the gas, the displacer piston has moved so that most of the gas is adjacent to the hot heat exchanger.
> 2. The heated gas increases in pressure and pushes the power piston to the farthest limit of the power stroke.
> 3. The displacer piston now moves, shunting the gas to the cold end of the cylinder.
> 4. The cooled gas is now **compressed by the flywheel momentum**. This takes less energy, since its pressure drops when it is cooled.

Notice in step 4, the compression is achieved by flywheel momentum. If the flywheel isn't spinning, (or is moving too slowly) there may not be sufficient momentum to compress the cooled gas. "Hitting the engine" provides this initial momentum.

Comment: This doesn't explain why step 2 isn't strong enough to get the engine rolling from standstill. Which is what I interpret the question to be about.

Comment: @Arthur in a way it does. Similarly, you could ask why a petrol (or a diesel engine) needs a starter, "why doesn't the power stroke just run the engine?"  .. well.. you need *to get* to the beginning of the power stroke first..

Comment: @CarlBerger But the way I read the question, the engine is in prime position for step 2 to happen. Would you need a starter on a combustion engine if the cylinder was filled with compressed air and fuel ready to ignite? Maybe, but not because you need the momentum of the engine to compress the air. Similarly, here, we don't need the momentum to compress any air. We already have warm, "high" pressure air pushing on the power piston, but the power piston refuses to move.